# How can i get the "Catalog Input Type for Store Owner" value

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, configurable-product

[image]

I want to get the value as Visual Swatch which is selected by the admin. This value color is a custom attribute but i want to know how it looks. How can i fetch this value.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $_attribute->getProductAttribute()->getData('swatch_input_type');
```